# Using asp.net mvc Partial View in ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to access a partial view in the ng-repeat
Here is the code

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in model">
                <td>
                    {{item.AssigneeName}}
                </td>
                <td>
                   {{item.NewsLetterName}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{item.Template }}
                </td>  
            </tr>
```

item.Template is returning the id of the template so I have created a partial view which takes id as input and returns the TemplateName as the string.I don't know how to call it in the ng-repeat.
Obviously.

`@Html.Action("GetTemplateById", "NewsLetter",new {{item.Template}})` doesn't work.

This is my first angular js project so any help will be appreciable.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`{{item.Template}}` converts to value in client side, while `@Html.Action("GetTemplateById", "NewsLetter"...` works on server side so on the time of partial render angular does not even exist or loaded

If you want to use partials you have to think a way, how to get that data on server side..